# MIPS Assembly while loop

Tags: java, assembly, mips

I am currently learning MIPS and while doing some exercises I came across one which is to write the Fibonacci sequence first in Java then convert it to MIPS Assembly. I only can use `beq`, `bne` and `slt` 
My Java code is the following:

```
    int n = 50; F_MAX  v
    int t1 = 0;
    int t2 = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while(t1 <= n)
    {
      System.out.print(t1 + " ")
      sum = t1 + t2
      t1 = t2
      t2 = sum;
     }
```

Meaning that if n = 50 if should print all the numbers before 50 (0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34)

My MIPS Assembly code is:

```
      la $s0, F_MAX
      lw $s0, 0($s0)         #$s0 = int n = F_MAX (50);



  addi  $t1, $zero, 0     # $t1 = int t1 = 0;
  addi  $t2, $zero, 1     # $t2 = int t2 = 1;
  addi  $t3, $zero, 0     # $t3 = int sum = 0


  while:

        beq $t1, $s0, Exit  #if t1 == 50 exit the program

        addi $v0, $zero, 1      # syscall code to print integer
        add $a0, $zero, $t1     # t1 to be printed
        syscall                 # print t1

        add $t3, $t1, $t2
        addi $t1, $t2, 0
        addi $t2, $t3, 0

        addi  $v0, $zero, 4     # syscall code to print a string
        la  $a0, COMMA
        syscall                 # print a comma (and a space)


        j while

Exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

But for some reason, it gives me overflow and prints all the possible positive numbers and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `t1 == 50` will always be `false`.

Comment: Is that because a number of the sequence may not ever be 50, meaning that ic could overjump this condition by t1 being 52 but not 50?

Comment: what is the next number in the sequence after 34?

Comment: It should be 55, therefore the condition is never true.Thanks

Comment: If the question has answered, I suggest posting the solution as an answer with the issue so that if a similar problem is encountered at a later date, there's an explanation here.

Comment: The solution was posted as an `EDIT`, thanks

Comment: please remove the edit from the question and paste it as answer, that is what the answer section is for.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. It is done now!

Answer (score 1):

So here is the updated code:
As the condition t1== 50 never was met it alwasys was false I had to use `slt` and `bne` instructions.

```
     la $s0, F_MAX
     lw $s0, 0($s0)                    #$s0 = int n = F_MAX (50);



     addi  $t1, $zero, 0               # $t1 = int t1 = 0;
     addi  $t2, $zero, 1               # $t2 = int t2 = 1;
     addi  $t3, $zero, 0               # $t3 = int sum = 0


           while:



           addi $v0, $zero, 1           # syscall code to print integer
           add $a0, $zero, $t1          # t1 to be printed
           syscall                      # print t1

           add $t3, $t1, $t2
           addi $t1, $t2, 0
           addi $t2, $t3, 0

           addi  $v0, $zero, 4          # syscall code to print a string
           la  $a0, COMMA
           syscall                      # print a comma (and a space)

           slt $t4, $t1, $s0            #if t1 < 50 $t4 = 1
           bne $t4, $zero, while        #if $t4 != $zero goto while

           slt $t4, $s0, $t1            #if 50 < $t1 $t4 = 1
           bne $t4, $zero, Exit         #if $t4 != $zero goto Exit

  Exit:
  li $v0, 10
  syscall
```